# display pagination in view with CActiveDataProvider model

Tags: yii

**I have following code in action:**

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
    'condition'=>'status='.Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
    'order'=>'sortOrder ASC',
    'with'=>'commentCount',               
));                        
$criteria->addSearchCondition('tags','home');
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array( 
    'pagination'=>array(   
        'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['postsPerPageHome'],
    ),
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));

$this->render('home',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,    
));
```

**home View:**

```
<?php foreach($dataProvider->getData() as $post) { ?>     
            // ....... displaying $post values
       <?php } ?>
```

How can I display the pagination in above view. I have searched for it, I found only using with zii.widgets.grid.CGridView but here I haven't use the widget.

Comment: Have you tried [CListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView)? It comes with pagination and you can select a view to render each item with.

Comment: @topher I think he wants a solution where pagination is not integrated. So he can push pagination by himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `CPagination` from the `CActiveDataProvider`:

```
<?php $this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'pages' => $dataProvider->pagination,
)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Hartl! sorry for simple question